# How to find difference between time stored in two strings in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writig a shell script where I am having a variable `t_1 = "10:51:45"` and I want to find the time difference between this time (assuming this is always in past) and current time

i tried doing this

```
curr_time=`date | cut -d " " -f 5`
A1=`date +%H:%M:%S -d $t_1`
C1=`date +%H:%M:%S -d $curr_time`

echo "$((C1 - A1))"
```

Getting below error  (curr_time = 23:10:03)
**syntax error in expression (error token is ":10:03 - 10:51:45")**

Answer (score 1):

```
t_1="10:51:45"
curr_time=`date | cut -d " " -f 5`

A1=`date +%s -d $t_1`
C1=`date +%s -d $curr_time`

echo "${C1} : ${A1}"
echo "$((C1 - A1))"
```

Comment: Good answer. One could make it *prettier* and simplify it by using `curr_time=$( date +%T )`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the dates into epoch format. This can be done in GNU awk:

```
awk -v etim="2021 02 08 23 27 00" '{ print strftime("%c",mktime(etim)-strftime("%s"),1) }' <<< /dev/null
```

Use awk's mktime and strftime functions to convert dates into epoch format and output the different between for example "2021/02/08 23:27:00" and now, in locale format. The format can be changed by changing "%c"